# Service version monitoring with zabbix

Tags: service, version, zabbix

Does anyone have any experience setting up service version monitoring in zabbix?
Currently we are using some usual suspect like java, tomcat, postgres etc on some of our servers but there no way to track their versions to keep them up to date. Would like to have zabbix as a tool that could tell which server has which version of the service, but i cant seem to find any information on that.

Only solution i could think of is using the userparameter option to get the data for it but then that wouldnt give me a viable way to track it, would simply give me the text of what it is. Is there any discovery methods for this or does anyone know a even better solution for it ?

Comment: While more or less related to software development this doesn’t feel like a programming question to me. Did you consider trying on [serverfault StackExchange](https://serverfault.com/), for example?

Comment: each template has its way to extract version information: for example, the postgres template do monitor the version, see https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/postgresql#:~:text:Posgresql%20version . For whatever reason, the [zabbix] tag on serverfault is almost empty, while it's used the most on stackoverflow.

Comment: Well for now i made a solution with userparameter and cmd command to get the version, i just thought as its a wide used thing to track versions, there might be a simply solution for it.